# Convert PHP array dynamic values to static key

Tags: php, arrays

Question:
I have a PHP array like this

```
Array
(
    [read] => 0
    [edit_posts] => 1
    [delete_posts] => 2
)
```

I have to change the values 0, 1, 2 into 1 like this

```
Array
(
    [read] => 1
    [edit_posts] => 1
    [delete_posts] => 1
)
```

How can I achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards
Uzair Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the same value to the whole array, run it simply and initialize it

```
array_walk($array,function(&$value){$value = 1;});
```

value is passed by reference.

Comment: Hi Eden, thanks for your help. I have found a workaround

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update.

If one of the solutions helped you, I would be happy if you marked the question as "solved", so that whoever reads the question after you can get an indication of the answer that will help him.

Comment: Hi Eden,
Acknowledge,

I have changed the from which I have created the array.

Something like this 
"delete_posts, edit_posts, 'create_posts"

to
"delete_posts:1, edit_posts:1, 'create_posts:1"

So these changes fulfilled my requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in multiple ways, but the simplest one is by [array_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) function.

```
<?php

$initial = [
  'read' => 0,
  'edit_posts' => 1,
  'delete_posts' => 2
];

$update = [
  'read' => 1,
  'edit_posts' => 1,
  'delete_posts' => 1
];

// Old values
var_dump($initial);

// Change with array_replace function same keys
$newArray = array_replace($initial, $update);

// Check if values changed
var_dump($newArray);
```

Working demo https://repl.it/@kallefrombosnia/array-change

Comment: Hi Kale, thanks for your help. I have found a workaround